# How to make button created with JQM clickable in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I want to make a div clickable within a jQuery Mobile powered site. The code I am using works in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox. Neither on Desktop nor on Android FF.

```
<button data-icon="eye">
   <a href="//heise.de">
       <div style="font-weight:regular;font-size:12px;color:black;font-weight:normal;">
           2nd line txt
       </div>
   </a>
</button>
```

The goal is to display a full size button with an icon on the left, vertically centered followed by a title and underneath a description line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the button tag and move the icon to the anchor tag:

```
<a data-role="button" href="//heise.de" data-icon="eye" data-ajax="false">
    <div style="font-weight:regular;font-size:12px;color:black;font-weight:normal;">
        2nd line txt
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. The first line needs to be in the same style as the normal links. I notices that they change black. Therefore I formeted it:  color:#38c; text-shadow: none; - Unfortunately upon click not the first line disapears (guess as shadow removed, there is nothing left. How could I maintain the same UI style as for the <a tag?

Comment: @merlin I am not sure if I follow you, but if you want to style anchor tags and buttons differently, you could use the technique in the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0j8qyLjq/2/